# How to output the JSON request URL in string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, getjson

I am using the following code to request a remote server JSON using a set of dynamic parameters created from an input form.  The request works fine but what I want to do is get a string of the request URL that was sent.

So the code looks like this:

```
$.getJSON(URL1, params1, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

URL1 is a variable with the base value for the domain I am requesting from:

```
var URL1 = "www.domain.com/api/stuff4stuff?jsonp=true&jcb=?"
```

And params1 is just a normal KVP object:

```
var Params1 = {APIINFO:12345,account:8675309}
```

Like I said my call is working fine, what I want is to get and output as a string the URL that JQuery produces and sends that request, including the random JQuery code it sends.

the URL that I am looking for will look someting like this, and I can view it in my network tab on the console just fine, but I need to get ahold of it in the code so I can display it and use it as a variable.

http://www.domain.com/api/stuff4stuff?jsonp=true&jcb=jQuery111108395918845199049_1405403521001&APIINFO=12345&account=8675309&_=1405403521002

Just to be clear, I am NOT looking for the current URL brought up by my request, I can get the browser window URL just fine, I am looking for the actual JQuery URL that it sends with the JSON request.

Comment: use lower level `$.ajax` and read API docs. `$.getJSON` is a convenience wrapper for `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably need is beforeSend(xhr,**plain**) - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8ZEE/3/)

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonp:"jcb",
   //jsonpCallback: "setYourCallback",
  data:params,
  beforeSend: function( xhr, plain) {
    console.log(xhr);
    $('.out').text(plain.url);
  }
})
.done(function( data ) {  . . .
```

Comment: Dylan: Sir, that is perfect, I was reading the ajax documentation but apparently I could not figure this out on my own, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get a hold of it in your PHP code - not in javascript code?

If you are certain that the request will not be over SSL:

```
$json_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

If the request might possibly come over SSL then you need to detect it:

```
$json_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
    $json_url = 'https://' . $json_url; 
} else {
    $json_url = 'http://' . $json_url; 
}
```